# Python: Display all options of a Unix wildcarded string with square brackets (reverse glob/fnmatch)

Tags: python, unix, wildcard, glob, fnmatch

I have a large dataset with rows of wildcarded strings e.g.

```
8145[012]
8146[01234]
8147[0134567]
```

I would like an efficient way to expand these out into unique rows for each combination, e.g.

```
81450
81451
81452
81460
81461
81462
etc...
```

What is the most efficient way to do this in Python 3.7?

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex to parse the wildcards, then iterate:

```
import re

data = ['8145[012]', '8146[01234]', '8147[0134567]']

for wildcard in data:
    base, combos = re.search(r'(\d+)\[(\d+)\]', wildcard).groups()
    for combo in combos:
        print(base + combo)
```

Output:

```
81450
81451
81452
81460
81461
81462
81463
81464
81470
81471
81473
81474
81475
81476
81477
```